# Error downloading Image files using PHP

Tags: php, image

I have written a PHP script to download image files it works as desired but it is not downloading files from certain hosts eventhough there doesn't seems to be any hotlinking restriction

take an example fo this image

```
http://new.picsbees.com/upload/big/2014/07/18/53c98c72cce24.jpg
```

if I paste it in browser it works but when I down load it using PHP then the downloaded  file has following data into it

```
<iframe src="http://202.125.134.154/webadmin/deny/?dpid=1&dpruleid=78&cat=23&ttl=-200&groupname=default&policyname=default&username=-&userip=39.142.127.202&connectionip=127.0.0.1&nsphostname=KHI275-NSP-08&protocol=policyprocessor&dplanguage=-&url=http%3a%2f%2fnew%2epicsbees%2ecom%2fupload%2fbig%2f2014%2f07%2f18%2f53c98c73413d8%2ejpg" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

And these are the core statments I'm using to download images

```
$local_image_file = fopen($filename, 'w');
chmod(filename,0755);
fwrite($local_image_file, $image_to_fetch);
fclose($local_image_file);
```

Please help me understand what is the issue

Comment: It appears to be some restriction on the server hosting the image.

Comment: It is not uncommon for servers to refuse connections from obvious scripted sources. If, by chance, you are using linux, you can exec wget. Otherwise, you need to use curl.

Comment: @kainaw what are the benifits of using wget or curl in this case?

Comment: Using wget means you just type "exec("wget http://some.url");" - nice and easy. Using curl means you have to type a few lines of curl setup, then fetch the data through curl and finally save it when you are done. All in all, wget does the curl work for you, but you will be limiting your code to machines that have wget.

Answer (score 1):

You're in Pakistan. So it's pure censorship. The server hosting your application, or your service provider is filtering what you're allowed to see.

[image]

Comment: I am using proxy so this is not the problem